# Read XML file with more than one value in one tag Using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have my XML file like this

```
<Customers>
  <Customer Name="Test_91" Code="91" Purpose="Supplier" />
  <Customer Name="Test_92" Code="92" Purpose="Receiver" />
</Customers>
```

I need to read this file with java and I use code like this:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLReaderDOM {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("Customers.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Customers");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


                    System.out.println("Customer id : "
                            + ((Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer").item(0)).getAttribute("Name"));
                    System.out.println("IataCode : "
                            + ((Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer").item(0)).getAttribute("Code"));
                    System.out.println("IcaoCode : "
                            + ((Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer").item(0)).getAttribute("Purpose"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the values of second record. which are details of customer "Test_92".

Can someone help me to read the values of N number of customers?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you have only one Customers node.. you are iterating it..
instead you iterate eElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer").. then you will get all the customer elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over the worn thing.

You get your list of elements called "customers" (you only have one of these) then loop over it.

Then inside your loop you find the list of "customer" take the first entry then extract an attribute (three times).

What you need to do is, take the first entry of your "customers" list, then get the list of "customer" and) loop over that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use xPath.

You can easily jump from node to node with it.

XML:

```
<Customers>
   <Customer name='f1'/>
   <Customer name='f1'/>
   <Customer name='f1'/>
</Customers>
```

Java:

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("Customers.xml"));

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/Customers/Customer").evaluate(xmlDocument,  XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue()); 
}
```

Outpot:

```
f1
f2
f3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the list of Customers tag, which is only in you document.

Try this,

```
 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Customer");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


                    System.out.println("Customer id : "
                            + ( eElement.getAttribute("Name")));
                    System.out.println("IataCode : "
                            + ( eElement.getAttribute("Code")));
                    System.out.println("IcaoCode : "
                            + ( eElement.getAttribute("Purpose")));
```

Comment: After updating code as per your suggestion It's working as per my requirement. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Koti Reddy Badam,Your welcome. If it has helped get, do consider up voting the answer or marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final String data = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element customers = simple.fromXml(data);
for (final Element customer : customers.children) {
    System.out.println(customer.attributes.get("Name"));
}
```

Will output:

```
Test_91
Test_92
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```